# fetch column max size of phpmyadmin by php coding or query

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to get the column max length by coding of `PHP` in my `PHP` page, that is specified when I created a table .
I mean I created a table in phpmyadmin and specified the max length of every column, but now I am on my `PHP` page, I can fetch all the that I have created but how can I fetch all the column size that are specified  by me .
I have to fetch on my `PHP` page.
Please give me an answer, I need it urgently

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code run this query:

`DESCRIBE your_table_name`;

Then have a look at the returned result set. In that result set you will have your columns, their data types and their length.